# Visualisation on Jpanel and big AffineTransformation, perhaps rounding error?

Tags: java, visualization, shapes, graphics2d

I have an visualization problem with several shapeitems on large scales. This is my Affinetransform:

renderMatrix    AffineTransform  (id=172)
    m00 160.60020751855694
    m01 0.0 
    m02 -3.608842342415596E7
    m10 -0.0
    m11 -160.600209194
    m12 8.40976407191E8 
    state   3
    type    69

My coordinate system is Gauß-Krüger and has very large x and y values. I think there is something wrong with large matrices. I draw them with following code:

```
Graphics2D g2 = get...;
Graphics2D.draw((Shape)getShape());
```

Hm, I'm not allowed to post pics. So, I try to explain. 
If I draw a circle, everything is ok on small scales, but if I draw at large scales at about 1:20, I get no circle but semi-circle. On the X-Axis it is ok. I think that is because the Gauß-Krüger Coords has a larger value on the Y-Axis. Its about 200.000 on x and 5.000.000 on y.

Has anybody an idea. Please give me a hint.